# MS SQL 2005: Strange Maintenance Plan SubPlans behaviour: each SP runs all the tasks of all other SP at odd times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, scheduling, maintenance-plan

(SQL Server 2005) I have a problem with scheduling a Maintenance Plan (MP) with 3 subplans (SP).

- SP1 is scheduled to run hourly,
- SP2 daily at 7.00 and
- SP3 on sundays at 8.00

Reading MP history I see that what happened (I know it seems crazy) is:

```
11: SP1 runs and executes all the tasks of SP1 SP2 and SP3
12: SP2 runs and does the same
13: SP3 runs and does the same
14: SP1 runs and does the same
```

From the job Activity monitor, SP1 has last run time at 14, SP2 and SP3 are *never* been executed.
All of the SP are scheduled correctly in the Job Activity Monitor (SP2 for tomorrow at 7, SP3 for next sunday at 8)

Do you have any idea what is happening?

Thankx a lot

Wentu

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation is that sp1 and sp2 collides daily at 7 and sp1 and sp3 collides on sunday, assuming that sp1 runs at wee hours 1,2,3 etc.

Would suggest you to change the sp1 to break even hours like 1.30,2.30

Please share your results